# iOS simulator present in external SSD showing black screen

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode13

I copied XCode 13 from a Mac system to my external SSD and when I started the simulator (using my Macbook Air running BigSur 11.6 with external SSD attached to it) then it showed black screen only.

[image]

How can I run the simulator normally and also run my app normally if I want to keep XCode in external SSD only?
Thanks!

Comment: Xcode needs to be in the /Applications folder.

Comment: @matt I wanted Xcode to be in external SSD due to free storage limit issue in my Macbook Air.

Comment: I understand, but you can't do that. Move something else to the external SSD instead, or get a bigger SSD. Anyway this is not a programming question and is off topic here...